# Is it safe to Implement a Merkle tree proof getting function on front-end of my website?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, solidity, nft

I'm developing a NFT website and was wondering if there are any security risks to having my Whitelist members Merkle tree in the front end instead of the usual way of sending an API call to the server to get a Merkle proof for an address. Keep in mind that the Merkle root would be set in my smart contract beforehand.

Comment: There's always security risks with keeping code like this sitting on the frontend of your application.  I think the best way would be to retrieve this information from the server instead of having it reside on your front end where someone could easily look at the request headers and make heads or tails of the details in the request.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll just stop being lazy...

Comment: Well I think it's good practice more than anything, and also will eliminate a lot of headaches in the future.